# Delete key at arbitrary depth in nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My goal is to delete a value from a nested dictionary.

Say I have the dictionary: `d = {'a': {'b': {'c': 10, 'd': 4}}}`.

I know that I could do: `del d['a']['b']['d']`.

But I have a list of nested keys, of unknown length. I want to produce the same behavior as above if I have the list `['a', 'b', 'd']`. The problem is that I don't know the length of the list of keys to use the above syntax.

For accessing a value with the same input, it's easy:

```py
def dict_get_path(dict_in: Dict, use_path: List):
    # Get the value from the dictionary, where (eg)
    # use_path=['this', 'path', 'deep'] -> dict_in['this']['path']['deep']
    for p in use_path:
        dict_in = dict_in[p]
    return dict_in
```

But I can't figure out any analogous way to *delete* an item without re-constructing the whole dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the same loop, except stop before the last key. Then use that to delete from the innermost dictionary.

```
def dict_del_path(dict_in: Dict, use_path: List):
    # Loop over all the keys except last
    for p in use_path[:-1]:
        dict_in = dict_in[p]
    # Delete using last key in path
    del dict_in[use_path[-1]]
```

Comment: Ah, I wasn't thinking about the fact that everything is references in Python; descending into the dictionary is still referencing the same dictionary, not defining anything new, so that's why it works. Simple solution -- thanks!